# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Unable to import local file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've been trying to deploy a Python (Flask framework) backend via Elastic Beanstalk.

Here's my error:

```
126:35532]   File "/opt/python/current/app/backend/src/application.py", line 6, in <module>
[Tue Jun 30 00:30:34.763891 2020] [:error] [pid 7666] [remote 172.31.3.126:35532]     from constants import *
[Tue Jun 30 00:30:34.763910 2020] [:error] [pid 7666] [remote 172.31.3.126:35532] ImportError: No module named constants
```

The Python service works perfectly locally (my method for testing locally is 1. create and source a brand new virtual environment in the top level folder, 2. run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and 3. run `python application.py`). But unsurprisingly I can't get it to work on AWS. Here is the tree structure of the backend folder.

```
backend
├── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── application.py
    ├── constants.py
    ├── entities
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── entity.py
    │   ├── job.py
    │   ├── user.py
```

The `WSGIPath` key (this is a config key you can set in the AWS console) is set to `backend/src/application.py` (I've also tried `src/application.py` and just plain ol' `application.py`).
As you can see in the logs, in `application.py` I am trying to import from `constants.py`. Because `constants.py` is my own file and not a 3rd party package, there's no entry for it in `requirements.txt`.

PS: I've read [AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Flask App Cannot Import Custom Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996993/aws-elastic-beanstalk-flask-app-cannot-import-custom-module) and I already have `__init__.py` in my folder.

Thanks!

Comment: What about `entities`? Can you import them? Just want to check if the issue is only related to `constants.py` or to the entire application.

Comment: Also can you try relative import (with dot): `from .constants import *`?

Comment: Show us your code and how you reference it? This is how I do it: `from base import constants`  `app = Flask(__name__) `

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a solution to this. I explicitly needed to add `sys.path.append("/opt/python/current/app/backend/src")` to the top of `application.py`. This in turn made `constants.py` discoverable on the AWS side.